# MySQL Commands not working on Windows CMD

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I have a problem with my MySQL setup on Windows. First of all I downloaded the latest Windows Installer from dev.mysql.com and installed the server. Now when I am trying to execute MySQL commands in the cmd (I already modified the PATH variable, and I am logged in as MySQL root user) the command won't be executed, there is just a "->" showing up.

I can only exit this "mode" by typing in "\q", and not by executing "exit".

Maybe you can help me, I really need MySQL for my Ruby on Rails project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MySQL command line lets you use multiple lines for a command, for instance

```
mysql> SELECT *
> FROM myTable
> LIMIT 0,10;
```

The use of the semicolon `;` is to tell the command line that that is the end of the command

So after your commands on the command line end it with a semicolon if you do not need to add anything else